# Match parent to absolute children? (responsive Carousel)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

*Have worked out a solution, see the bottom!*

I'm experimenting with a responsive carousel (fluid). I have elements stacked on top of each other so that the width can be fluid depending on the width of the parent. The issue is I need the parent to have overflow hidden which is not possible with children that are absolute positioned.

Tip on cleaning up the JS are appreciated too!

Does anyone have any ideas how to improve this or alternatives? Heres the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j35fy/5/

```
.carousel-wrap {
    position: relative;
}

.carousel-item {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}

$.fn.mwCarousel = function(options) {
    //Default settings.
    var settings = $.extend({
        changeWait: 3000,
        changeSpeed: 800,
        reveal: false,
        slide: true,
        autoRotate: true
    }, options );

    var CHANGE_WAIT = settings.changeWait;
    var CHANGE_SPEED = settings.changeSpeed;
    var REVEAL = settings.reveal;
    var SLIDE = settings.slide;
    var AUTO_ROTATE = settings.autoRotate;
    var $carouselWrap = $(this);
    var SLIDE_COUNT = $carouselWrap.find('.carousel-item').length;
    var rotateTimeout;

    if (AUTO_ROTATE) {
        rotateTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
            rotateCarousel(SLIDE_COUNT-1);
        }, CHANGE_WAIT);
    }

    function rotateCarousel(slide) {
        if (slide === 0) {
            slide = SLIDE_COUNT-1;
            rotateTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
                $('.carousel-item').css('margin', 0);
                $('.carousel-item').show();
            }, CHANGE_WAIT);
            if (REVEAL) {
                $($carouselWrap.find('.carousel-item')[slide]).slideToggle(CHANGE_SPEED);
            } else if (SLIDE) {
                var carouselItem = $($carouselWrap.find('.carousel-item')[slide]);
                carouselItem.show();
                var itemWidth = carouselItem.width();
                carouselItem.animate({margin: 0}, CHANGE_SPEED);
            } else {
                $($carouselWrap.find('.carousel-item')[slide]).fadeIn(CHANGE_SPEED);
            }

            slide = slide+1;
        } else {
            if (REVEAL) {
                $($carouselWrap.find('.carousel-item')[slide]).slideToggle(CHANGE_SPEED);
            } else if (SLIDE) {
                var carouselItem = $($carouselWrap.find('.carousel-item')[slide]);
                var itemWidth = carouselItem.width();
                carouselItem.animate({marginLeft: -itemWidth, marginRight: itemWidth}, CHANGE_SPEED);
            } else {
                $($carouselWrap.find('.carousel-item')[slide]).fadeOut(CHANGE_SPEED);
            }
        }

        rotateTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
            rotateCarousel(slide-1);
        }, CHANGE_WAIT);
    }
}

$('.carousel-wrap').mwCarousel();
```

**Solution**
The first slide actually never moves (last one visible) so that one is set to position: static and all works nicely.

Comment: I can't really understand what the issue seems to be apart from the little overlap on the left which I think you could sort out with `z-index` manipulation

Comment: Have edited the fiddle to make a bit more clear. How would z-index manipulation work?

Answer (score 1):

I think by just changing your CSS you're actually there:

```
.carousel-wrap {
    position: relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    height:80%;
    width:90%;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/j35fy/2/

Comment: I could have made my fiddle a bit clearer, sorry! I've updated to include some other content (http://jsfiddle.net/j35fy/4/). The height of carousel wrap needs to match it's contents, the height of its contents will be fluid depending on browser width. I feel like I need to figure an entirely different route!

Comment: Yes this really doesn't make sense to me? Howcome you are giving the `container` a height of 1000px? What are you exactly trying to do?  You want it responsive but then you say it needs to be height of contents?

Comment: That was just there to show a colored area to highlight that the carousel should not slide over the blue area. So the .container is just the page, the size of that doesnt matter. The carousel-wrap should match the height of the images (which are fluid so the height changes depending on screen width). The reason the wrap should match the height is so I can set overflow hidden on it so that the images don't move on top of the blue area when they slide. Hopefully that's clearer!

Comment: So are you telling me you change the image heights in CSS depending on media queries?  In which case you can set the height the same way of the `carousel-wrap`?

Comment: No the image height is fluid in the same sense that if you change the viewport width in the jsfiddle the image height changes relative to the width of the viewport (no breakpoints). I'm thinking this is impossible without setting the height in JS, which is not ideal! May have to completely rethink this...

Answer (score 0):

Discovered the solution is in fact simple, as the first slide in the DOM (the last you see) never actually moves itself I can set that one slide to be position: static and thus the carousel wrap will set it's height accordingly.

http://jsfiddle.net/j35fy/7/

```
.container {
    background: aliceblue;
    padding: 3em;
}
.carousel-wrap {
    position: relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.carousel-item:first-child {
    position:static;
}

.carousel-item {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
img {
    width: 100%;
}
```